# how to make a modal maximized in tornadofx?

Tags: javafx, tornadofx

I need to open the modal maximized .
i tried

```
class BookingDetailView : Fragment("Booking Details") {
    override val root: BorderPane by fxml()
    init {
        modalStage?.isMaximized = true
    } 
}
```

edit:
tried to override onDock()

```
class BookingDetailView : Fragment("Booking Details") {
override val root: BorderPane by fxml()
override fun onDock() {
//modalStage is null here. when i tried to debug . 
    **modalStage?.isMaximized = true**

}
```

}

Invoked from this view :

```
class FindRoomView : View("Find Room") {
override val root: BorderPane by fxml()
private val dpArrivalDate: JFXDatePicker  by fxid()
private val tparrivalTime: JFXTimePicker by fxid()
private val dpDepartureDate: JFXDatePicker by fxid()
private val dpDepartureTime: JFXTimePicker by fxid()
private val btnFindRoom: JFXButton by fxid()
private val cbAdult: JFXComboBox<*> by fxid()
private val cbChildren: JFXComboBox<*> by fxid()
private val btnClear: JFXButton by fxid()
private val btnAdvanceBooking: JFXButton by fxid()
private val btnBookNow: JFXButton by fxid()
val count = FXCollections.observableArrayList<Int>()
//  val selections = FXCollections.observableArrayList<AdvanceBookingRoomModel>()
val availability = listOf(RoomType("AC"), RoomType("Non-AC")).observable()

init {
    //    model.item = this
    // model.count.value +=1..50
    //   (1..50).forEach { i -> model.count.value.add(i) }
    //    dpArrivalDate.bind(model.arrivalDateProperty)
    cbChildren.items = count
    cbAdult.items = count
    //   btnBookNow.setOnAction { bookNow() }
    btnBookNow.action { bookNow() }

}

private fun bookNow() {
    //  openInternalWindow(BookingDetailView::class,owner = root)
    find(BookingDetailView::class).openWindow()
}
}
```

it does'not work.
I also want to have minimize and maximize button on modal.
How to do that?
[image: Output of Edvin's code]

Answer (score 1):

The `modalStage` is not yet created when your Fragment is initialized, so `modalStage` is always null at this point. Override `onDock` instead and set `isMaximized = true` there.

You can pass a `stageStyle` parameter to `openModal` and `openWindow` to control available icons in the created Window. Here is a complete application that shows how to access `modalStage` in `onDock`:

```
class ModalApp : App(FindRoomView::class)

class FindRoomView : View("Find Room") {
    override val root = stackpane {
        button("Book now").action {
            find(BookingDetailView::class).openWindow()
        }
    }
}

class BookingDetailView : Fragment("Booking Details") {
    override val root = borderpane()

    override fun onDock() {
        modalStage?.isMaximized = true
        println(modalStage)
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried to override onDock(). This doesnt work either.

Comment: Can you post a minimal, complete sample that shows the issue?

Comment: modalStage is still null inside onDock(){}. why?

Comment: I have edited the onDock(). @Edvin this does'nt work for the first time. but from sencond time when i click button to open the window. it works. why is so? I tried to debug and i found modalStage is still "null" inside onDock().

Comment: class BookingDetailView : Fragment("Booking Details") {
override val root: BorderPane by fxml()
override fun onDock() {
//modalStage is null here. when i tried to debug . 
    **modalStage?.isMaximized = true**

}

Comment: I updated my answer with a complete app that uses this technique. Can you run this exact code and see if the stage is available?

Comment: I created new project with exact your code. I updated my question with the screen shoot for your code. as you can see. we got the stage (in console) but the window is not maximized yet.

Comment: Did it print the stage instance to the console or did it print null?

Comment: It prints stage instance. It's not null.

Comment: Something else must interfere with the mode change. Try wrapping the maximized call in `runLater` to see if that solves the problem: runLater {
    modalStage?.isMaximized = true
}

Comment: try to use currentStage?.isMaximized = true